# Using return/enter instead of tab skips an element in UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'd like to be able to use return/enter to get to the next `TextBox` in a UWP app. (I've included here a sample app, but my actual app has a lot of rows, so I don't want to have to add a `KeyDown` event to every `TextBox` if I can avoid it.)

I have added `KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown"` to my `Grid` then, if the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I call

```
FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next)
```

It skips from the first element to the third element to the fifth. Tab works fine without skipping any elements.

Here's XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="CatApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CatApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">First:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">Second:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">Third:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">Fourth:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4">Fifth:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5">Sixth:</TextBlock>


        <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  TabIndex="1" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  TabIndex="2" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  TabIndex="3" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  TabIndex="4" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"  TabIndex="5" ></TextBox>
        <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"  TabIndex="6" ></TextBox>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace CatApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
            {
                FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a known bug which has been in WinRT `TextBox` since Windows 8 and it appears it has been finally fixed in the **Fall Creators Update (16299)**. If your app is targeting this version of Windows (or later), it should work properly.

To see what is happening put a breakpoint on the `if` in the event handler. When you press any key, the handler is executed once. But when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it is actually executed twice in a succession, which causes your focus to jump two lines.

The fix is quite easy - it is enough to mark the event as handled:

```
private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This will prevent the handler from executing twice and your app will work as expected :-) .

Comment: Thank you - setting e.Handled to true has fixed it. I really appreciate your help. (Btw, I can't update to 16299 as my colleague has put a restriction of 14393 on our project.)

Comment: Glad to hear that :-), happy coding!